# MSAccess - Updating all fields in form when selecting one field from listbox

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I have a form which has the following fields

Club   Player  Handicap  Membership Number  Score

I have set the Club as a list box

how do I get the other fields to automatically polulate when I select the Club

thankyou...Julie T

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about forms you maybe referring to controls not to fields.
You need to provide more information about the source of your data.
Are all data loaded into a listbox and you want to populate textboxes with those values?
If so, listboxes have a property called column:

```
Me.Mylistbox.Column(0)
```

will refer to the first column of your listbox, typically the Id.

HTH,

Diego